# new FormData printing empty object after reduce method

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to turn the data inputed by a user into a form into an object using the reduce method but console logging returns an empty object regardless if I put in any input.

Any ideas?

```
<form id="todo-form">
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" required />
  <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" placeholder="Description" required />
  <select id="status" name="status">
    <option value="completed">Completed</option>
    <option value="pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="incomplete">Incomplete</option>
  </select>
  <select id="priority" name="priority">
    <option value="low">Low</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="high">High</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
  var form = document.getElementById('todo-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    var todo = Array.from(Object.entries(formData)).reduce((map, [key, value]) => ({
      ...map,
      [key]: value
    }), {})
    console.log(todo);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: `Object.entries()` does not get you the entries of a `FormData` instance. [`formData.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) does

Comment: Btw, use `Object.fromEntries()` instead of that `reduce`

Comment: Thanks Bergi, formData.entries() did the trick!